# How to implement foreach delegate in razor viewengine?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The following code works for webform view engine.

```
<% Model.Categories.ForEach(x => { %>
    <li><a href="#">@x.Name</a></li>
<% }) %>
```

I wrote the above code as below in razor view:

```
@Model.Categories.ForEach(x => {
  <li><a href="#">@x.Name</a></li>
})
```

But this doesn't work.

Can anyone suggest, Is there any way to achieve this in razor view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're working on adding support for that but currently it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I found how to implement delegates in Razor based on the following article by Phil Haack.
[Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx)

Here is the extension code for IEnumerable:

```
public static HelperResult ForEachTemplate<TEntity>(
        this IEnumerable<TEntity> items, 
        Func<RowEntity<TEntity>, HelperResult> template)
{
    return new HelperResult(writer =>
               {
                   var index = 0;
                   foreach (var item in items)
                   {
                       template(new RowEntity<TEntity> { 
                               Index = index, 
                               Value = item }).WriteTo(writer);
                       index++;
                   }
               });
}

public class RowEntity<TEntity>
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public TEntity Value { get; set; }
}
```

View Model is :

```
// IEnumerable<Person>

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the use of that extension methods:

```
@Model.ForEachTemplate(@<p>Index: @item.Index Name: @Item.Value.Name</p>)
```

Comment: FWIW you could probably get by with naming this Method just ForEach, since the method signature has `Func<RowEntity<TEntity>, HelperResult> template` as a dependency I doubt you would ever inadvertently invoke this method instead of your standard ForEach(x=> method.

Comment: Why are people so obsessed with writing `foreach` loops with delegates when it's far simpler to write *and read* the dumb old `foreach` syntax? I really hope that nobody actually does this.

Answer (score 7):

Is there any reason you need to do that?

```
@foreach(var x in Model.Categories) {
    <li><a href="#">@x.Name</a></li>
}
```

Above does the exact same thing, and is more idiomatic.

I can't see a way to output the `.ForEach()` delegate result using the Razor syntax. Razor expects called methods or invoked properties to return a value, which is then emitted into the view output. Because `.ForEach()` doesn't return anything, it doesn't know what to do with it:

> Cannot explicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

You can have the iterator index quite tersely like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Categories.Select((cat, i) => new { Item = cat, Index = i })) {
   <li><a href="#">@x.Index - @x.Item.Name</a></li>
}
```

If you want to define this as an extension method, instead of an anonymous type, you can create a class to hold the `Item, Index` pair, and define an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` which `yield`s the items in the original enumerable wrapped in this construct.

```
public static IEnumerable<IndexedItem<T>> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
{ 
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T item in input)
        yield return new IndexedItem<T> { Index = i++, Item = item };
}
```

The class:

```
public class IndexedItem<T>
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
@foreach(var x in Model.Categories.WithIndex()) {
    <li><a href="#">@x.Index - @x.Item.Name</a></li>
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to know how to make delegate work in razor. For example I have an extension method for enumerable like 
.ForEach<T>((x,index) => { ... }). This pass index to the view so I can add alternative row in a table. I know it can be done without this extension methods but using extension methods I can remove lot of code.

Comment: @learner: Edited my answer. I don't think this is possible in Razor.

Comment: -1 answer doesn't answer OP's question, working solution provided by OP